# Can a fragment catch back key presses?

Tags: android

Is it possible for a fragment to catch back key presses? I have a view that's displayed on screen (almost looks like a dialog), and when the user hits the back key, I want to dismiss it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the `FragmentTransaction` and the `addToBackStack()`??

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this following code. It's work !!

```
public void loadFragment(Fragment fragmentB, String tag) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentB, tag);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);

    ft.commit();
}
```